# Using apply() to generate all subset regression for ARIMA

Tags: r, arima

I am trying to generate fitted models for all the combinations for ARIMA(p,0,q), say, for p<=5 and q<=5.

My ultimate goal is to select the best model based on BIC, AIC and RMSE, etc(computed using accuracy).

Using a loop method, I was able to get the desired output,

```
pdq_index_mat=expand.grid(0L:5L,0L,0L:5L)
# access the following link for the csv and run the following code to access the data for replication purposes for the following code/error
# https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByLULem4QYiEcDB2OTJaejdVUkk
tsdf<-as.ts(read.csv(file.choose()))

#Loop method
ic_result_mat<-c()
reg<-c()
y<-tsdf[,"psoda"] #dependent variable of interest
for(i in 1:nrow(pdq_index_mat)){
  # print(as.numeric(pdq_index_mat[i,])) serve as the c(p,0,q) to indicate which ARIMA of interest
  reg<-arima(tsdf[,"psoda"],order=as.numeric(pdq_index_mat[i,]))
  ic_result_mat<-rbind(ic_result_mat,c(BIC=BIC(reg),AIC=AIC(reg),accuracy(reg)[,c("RMSE","MAE","MPE","MAPE")]))
  # uncomment the following line for the first error
  # colnames(tsdf)[ncol(tsdf)+i]<-paste0("ARIMA(",paste0(pdq_index_mat[i,],collapse=","),")")
}
colnames(ic_result_mat)<-c("BIC","AIC","RMSE","MAE","MPE","MAPE")
rownames(ic_result_mat)<-paste0("ARIMA(",do.call(paste,c(pdq_index_mat[1:nrow(ic_result_mat),],sep=",")),")")
```

Except with 1 flaw, I wasn't able to generate rownames inside the loop 
(eg. ARIMA(0,0,0) for the first row), and prompting the following error:

```
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "ARIMA(1,0,0)" : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

or

```
 Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("ARIMA(0)", "ARIMA(0)", "ARIMA(0)" : 
    attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
```

As for using the `apply()` method, I am stuck even getting the list of regression

```
#List method
ic_result_mat<-c()
y<-tsdf[,"psoda"] #dependent variable of interest
reg_lst<-apply(pdq_index_mat,1,function(i)arima(y,order=as.integer(pdq_index_mat[i,])))
```

and prompting the following error:

```
Error in if (!is.numeric(order) || length(order) != 3L || any(order <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Sorry, not a professional coder. Any help from the pro is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not just using `forecast::auto.arima`?

Comment: Please make it reproducable to we can look into where your errors come from.

Comment: *access the following link for the csv*...where is this link?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have added the csv file link in.

@ChrisHaug: Thank you for your suggestion, I have tried using it once, but probably due to my computer performance, it was very slow. But during my second retry it become ok. Nevertheless, I wish to figure out the way of using apply and loop, think of it as a practice for newbie like me. Anyway, thanks again for the suggestion